# how to show a button(link) in a new line (css or jquery)

Tags: jquery, css

I want to make a new line after my last  of my form. In the new Line should be the "remove-link".

my HTML:

```
<div class="subform dynamic-form">

<label for="id_delivery_set-0-price">

    Price:

</label>
<input id="id_delivery_set-0-price" type="number" step="0.01" name="delivery_set-0-price"></input>
<label for="id_delivery_set-0-amount">

    Amount:

</label>
<input id="id_delivery_set-0-amount" type="number" name="delivery_set-0-amount" min="0"></input>
<label for="id_delivery_set-0-humidity" style="display: none;">

    Humidity:

</label>
<input id="id_delivery_set-0-humidity" type="number" name="delivery_set-0-humidity" style="display: none;"></input>
<label for="id_delivery_set-0-weight" style="display: none;">

    Weight:

</label>
<input id="id_delivery_set-0-weight" type="number" step="0.01" name="delivery_set-0-weight" style="display: none;"></input>
<input id="id_delivery_set-0-DELETE" type="hidden" name="delivery_set-0-DELETE"></input>
<input id="id_delivery_set-0-bill" type="hidden" name="delivery_set-0-bill"></input>
<input id="id_delivery_set-0-id" type="hidden" name="delivery_set-0-id"></input>
<a class="btn del btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)">

    remove

</a>
```

Picture:
[image: Dynamic Form]

I want the "remove-link" under my "amount-input-field". 
How to do this in css?

```
.subform {
     display: inline-block;
}

.del {
     ????
}
```

A solution with jquery is also Ok.

Comment: Have you tried `display: block;`?

Comment: yes I tried. But this don't work for me.

Comment: You don't need `</input>`

Comment: this is all generated by django.

Comment: You are the developer. It is your responsibility to ensure you have valid HTML.

Comment: I think this tag is no problem. Because it works, and django create this tag for every input tag. So it would be a lot of work to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

If your `input` elements are inline currently, just set the button to:

`.btn-danger{ display: block;}`

Comment: Then you must have some floats in there. Show us a fiddle or something, your full css